# stop javascript loading on mobile

Tags: javascript

I have a responsive page. On this page I have a button that opens up in a pop up window/modal. I have given this button a href with a working link as a fallback. On mobile, I would like the pop-up to be disabled and open the link in a new window.

Th javascript code I have so far is...

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 480px)" );

if (mq.matches) {

 function Modal(){

    //Code inside modal
}

}
else {
    function Modal(){
        exit();
    }   
}
```

Now with this code, this does work on mobile, and opens the link in new window, however for some reason, the main screen also does this (By main screen, I mean windows with a width greater than 480px).

This should not happen on the main screen, only the mobile screen. Is `exit()` the correct command I should be using?

I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using (min-width:481px) instead. anything > 480 should have matches, while anything 480 or less will not.

min-width matches using a >=, which includes the mobile screen's width =480px.